# Changing a directory to a subdirectory specified by the User

Tags: c#, chdir

I need to change the directory on the server to a subdirectory on the server, but it has to be specified by the client.

I've tried numerous ways to try and get this working properly but no solution.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post an example of how are you trying to achieve this?

Comment: string directorychoice = reader.ReadLine();
                            if (File.Exists(directorychoice))
                            {
                                //Set the current directory.
                                Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(directorychoice);
                            }

                            writer.WriteLine(directorychoice);


and in the client, i have 
string directorychoice = Console.ReadLine();

                                Console.WriteLine("You have changed the directory to", directorychoice);

Comment: I think @pollirrata meant post it in your question ;)